# How does the VLC player calculate the total length of the timeline of the fmp4 file?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, h.264, aac, fmp4

use VLC player to play fmp4 file, the player shows the total length of the timeline port is 0, but video can play normally.How does the player calculate the total length of the timeline of the fmp4 file?
How should I modify the time parameter of fmp4 box.
[image]

Comment: It probably just loads a fragment after fragment until EOF. you should be able to calculate the duration by parsing metadata in each fragment header (such as number of samples in a fragment etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add a Movie Fragment Random Access Box ('mfra') with the correct 'tfra' and 'mfro' to the end of your file. 'mfra' is essentially and index of all fragments.
The 'tfra' boxes contain the presentation times for each fragment.

It worked for me: [image]